# Save part of matching pattern to variable

Tags: regex, bash, variables, extract

I want to extract a substring matching a pattern and save it to a file. An example string:

```
Apr 12 19:24:17 PC_NMG kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I want to extract the part between the brackets, in this case `[sdf]`.

I tried to do something like `grep -e '[$subtext]'` to save the text in the brackets to a variable. Of course it doesn't work, but I am looking for a way similar to this. It would be very elegant to include a variable in a regex like this. What can I do best?

Thanks!

Comment: I presume that the capture should be **between** the brackets, ie. noninclusive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's probably a better way using bash only, but:

```
echo 'Apr 12 19:24:17 PC_NMG kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk' \
| sed -s 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
```

As Jurgen points out, this matches non-matching lines.  If you don't want to output nonmatching lines, use '-n' so it doesn't output the pattern, and '/p' to outputs the pattern when it matches.

```
| sed -n 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/p'
```

Comment: This also prints non-matching lines

Comment: OS X users will needs to remove the -s option as it is not supported.

Comment: @Stephen I have a similar problem `echo '\title{\hypertarget{A64L}{A64L(3)}}' | sed -e s/\\\\section\{/\\\\section\*{/g -e /\\\\title\{\\\\hypertarget\{\(.*\)\}\{.*\(3\)\}\}/a\\\\\\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\1}`  I expect the result as `\title{\hypertarget{A64L}{A64L(3)}}` `\addcontents{toc}{section}{A64L}`.

Answer (score 14):

`BASH_REMATCH` is an array containing groups matched by the shell.

```
$ line='Apr 12 19:24:17 PC_NMG kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk'
$ [[ $line =~ \[([^]]+)\] ]]; echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
sdf
```

If you want to put this in a loop, you can do that; here's an example:

```
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line =~ \[([^]]+)\] ]] ; then
    drive="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    do_something_with "$drive"
  fi
done < <(dmesg | egrep '\[([hsv]d[^]]+)\]')
```

This approach puts no external calls into the loop -- so the shell doesn't need to `fork` and `exec` to start external programs such as `sed` or `grep`. As such, it is arguably significantly cleaner than other approaches offered here.

BTW, your initial approach (using grep) was not that far off; using `grep -o` will output only the matching substring:

```
$ subtext=$(egrep -o "\[[^]]*\]" <<<"$line")
```

...though this includes the brackets inside the capture, and thus is not 100% correct.

Comment: but then bash's while read loop is significantly slower for iterating a big file as compared to awk (etc). By the way, i get no output for your first version without the while loop. The `]` in your character ranges should not be escaped.

Comment: @ghostdog - updated, thanks. I *do* get output even as-is, but that's bash 4. I agree that the read loop is slow -- filtering once on the input side is much, much better than filtering inside your loop, and you *have* to have a loop if you're going to match more than one line.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I gues you can answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/413680/176227 similar solution needed. Just correct the regex.

Answer (score 4):

Match against regex, replace using grouping and only print if regex matched:

```
sed -n "s/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/p"
```

Answer (score 1):

sed is greedy, so the sed answers will miss out some of the data if there are more `[]` pairs in your data. Use the grep+tr solution or you can use awk

```
$ cat file
[sss]Apr 12 19:24:17 PC_NMG kernel: sd 11:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI removable disk [tag] blah blah

$ awk -F"[" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/\]/){sub("].*","",$i)};print $i}}' file
sss
sdf
tag
```